# Return entity key from datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, pull-request

I would like to know if there's a way to return a key from entity specific using nodejs and datastore.

Example:
I have an entity that has name and age parameters. I would like to retrieve the key by name.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was a similar question asked and addressed on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268394/node-js-datastore-query-get-key)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268394/node-js-datastore-query-get-key).

Also, review the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/) about the Google Cloud Datastore-Node.js client which could be helpful in your implementations.