# How to get entity id from entity data with Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Here is the output I am getting from Google Cloud Datastore query in NodeJS:

```
{
  photo: null,
  login: 'test@example.com',
  [Symbol(KEY)]:
   Key {
     namespace: undefined,
     id: '5637017136267264',
     kind: 'Users',
     path: [Getter] } 
}
```

I want to get [Symbol(KEY)].Key.id value in NodeJS. I am using [gstore-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gstore-node)

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40293280/2477472](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40293280/2477472)